# sort array of size n

Tags: c++, c, arrays

if an array of size n has only 3 values 0 ,1 and 2 (repeated any number of times) what is the best way to sort them. best indicates complexity. consider space and time complexity both

Comment: What does best mean in this case?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "best" - most convenient ? fastest ? most efficient in terms of storage ? most portable ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Count the occurences of each number and afterward fill the array with the correct counts, this is `O(n)`

Comment: aka pigeonhole sort, aka radix sort.

Comment: @ Andreas the value of n may be quiet large so counting may be a bit troublesome in some cases

Comment: @Grv Troublesome in what way? Like performance wise or that the count doesn't fit in an `int` or something?

Comment: @Grv: You're not going to get better than `O(n)` for sorting an array of size `n`.

Comment: @Andreas i was talking about the size of int in some compiler. if you use long int or others they may degrade performance, apart from that the solution is good cause i also think that it is the best complexity o(n)

Comment: why would you use long int when you know the values are 0, 1 or 2?

Comment: @Will, One O(n) can be 100 times faster than another O(n).
@Grv: No matter what sorting algorithm you use, you of course need to know if the array dimension fits in int.

Comment: @jk: the size of the ints used need to hold the counts, not the values 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: @PauliL: If the count of array elements exceeds the what will fit into a `size_t` variable, you'll likely have many more problems than figuring out a decent sort.

Answer (score 3):

Sound's a lot like Dijkstra's Dutch National Flag Problem.

If you need a solution that doesn't use counting, check out http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Sort/Flag/

Answer (score 2):

Untested C-style solution:

```
int count[3] = {0, 0, 0};

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    ++count[array[i]];

int pos = 0;
for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c)
    for (int i = array[c]; i; --i)
        array[pos++] = c;
```

Comment: `unsigned` or `size_t` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell two-liner:

```
count xs = Map.toList $ Map.fromListWith (+) [ (x, 1) | x <- xs ]

countingSort xs = concatMap ( \(x, n) -> replicate n x) (count xs)

> countingSort [2,0,2,1,2,2,1,0,2,1]
[0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
```