# Looking for a O(N) sort for an array with only 3 possible values

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to extend the following code to sort the array if I added a third value 'C'. Would this be possible to do while retaining only one loop. The following code will sort an array with two possible values 'A' and 'B'.

```
public class TestSort
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        char f[] = {'A','B','B','A','B','B','A','B','A','A','B'};
        int k = 0, t = f.length-1;

        while(k < t)
        {
            if(f[k] == 'A')
                k = k + 1;
            else if(f[k] == 'B')
            {
                char m = f[t];
                f[t] = f[k];
                f[k] = m;
                t = t - 1;
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\nSorted List\n");
        for(char i : f)
            System.out.print(i + ", ");

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is an attempt. I don't know if I'm on the right track.

```
public class TestSort
{
    static char f[] = {'C','A','B','A','C','B','A','B','C','C','B','A','B'};
    //static char f[] = {'A','A','A','A','A','C','A','C','A','A','C','A','C'};
    //static char f[] = {'C','B','B','B','C','B','B','B','C','C','B','C','B'};
    //static char f[] = {'A','B','B','B','A','B','C','B','A','A','B','A','B'};
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int j = 0, k = 0, t = f.length-1, l = f.length-1;

        while(t >= 0)
        {
            if(f[k] == 'A')
                k = k + 1;
            else if(f[k] == 'B')
            {
                char m = f[j];
                f[j] = f[k];
                f[k] = m;
                j = j + 1;
            }
            else if(f[k] == 'C')
            {
                char m = f[l];
                f[l] = f[k];
                f[k] = m;
                l = l - 1;
            }

        for(char i : f)
            System.out.print(i + ", ");

        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there as many A's as B's as C's?

Comment: A search for Dutch National Flag on stackoverflow brought this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621905/sort-array-of-size-n (and others).

Comment: There is an unknown frequency of A, B and C's and the array length is unknown.

Comment: Counting sort! Counting sort! Counting sort!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like:

```
public sort(char[] array) {
    int[] frequencies = new int[3];
    for(char c : array) {
        if (c == 'A')
            frequencies[0]++;
        if (c == 'B')
            frequencies[1]++;
        if (c == 'C')
            frequencies[2]++;
    }
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies[0]; i++) {
        array[index++] = 'A';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies[1]; i++) {
        array[index++] = 'B';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies[2]; i++) {
        array[index++] = 'C';
    }
}
```

Comment: if youre going to store the frequencies, you should do something like array[frequencies[i]++] = C; then it can be done in one for loop

Comment: @Ben: No, you need to first count the whole array, then output the result.

Answer (score 0):

Is the requirement "keep it O(n)", or "keep one loop" ?

Adding a second (non-nested) loop wouldn't change the O(n) quality.  then you could do it in two steps: first push all the 'A's to the start and a second one to push all the 'C's to the end.

Comment: The goal is to keep it the same as the sample code I gave just maybe more if statements inside the while loop and more position vars.